# Regular Expression Anything But A SSN

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex code in c#.

```
^((?!(\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4})).)*$")
```

They only thing I care about is the textbox doesn't match a ssn.  [###-##-####]
How do i make the regex match everything except SSN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?!(\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4})$).*
```

this worked for me at
http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do a regex for an SSN, and then do an `if (! m.Success)`?

Edit: There are two reasons I'd do it this way:

1) Most importantly, it will be much easier for someone else to read. Even someone who hasn't seen many regexes will be able to read the straight matches-SSN regex. And of course, sometimes that "someone else" is you in six months.

2) Secondly, the more complex a regex becomes, the more likely it is that it matches something you don't expect. For this reason, I think it's best to use a simpler regex if you can.